# Formula put in cells with VBA not calculating

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, calculation

Put the code I'm working with at the bottom.

I am trying to enter a set of formulas in a range with code. The formulas enter correctly, but they only calculate if I click on each cell, click on the formula box, and hit enter.

I've tried all suggestions I can find online, hence the last three lines of code. It's not a matter of the cells changing format, they remain General after the code runs. I'm completely stumped.

```
Sub ButtonTest()
    Dim Number As Integer
    Number = Range("M2").Value
    Dim TestArray() As String
    ReDim TestArray(0, 1 To Number)
    Dim Values As Integer
    Dim RangeValues As Integer
    Dim Variable As Integer
    Variable = 3
    TestArray(0, 1) = "=1"

    For Values = 2 To Number
        TestArray(0, Values) = "=" & Cells(3, Variable).Address & "+1"
        Variable = Variable + 1
    Next Values

    Range("C3:" & Cells(3, Number + 2).Address).Formula = TestArray
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter a formula from an array use `.FormulaArray` rather than `.Formula`

```
Range("C3:" & Cells(3, Number + 2).Address).FormulaArray = TestArray
```

Comment: Oh man, after all these years and only now...! Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm off the mark here, but I always had the impression that formulas couldn't be written to a `Range` in an array (as you would with values, for example). I believe you have to write one cell at a time.

There may be a method that can be called to convert array values to evaluated cells, but I don't know of it - be happy to hear if anyone can enlighten me though.

In the meantime, the code below gives an example of how your code could be made to work:

```
Dim iterationCount As Long, i As Long
Dim cell As Range

iterationCount = Sheet1.Range("M2").Value

Set cell = Sheet1.Range("C3")
cell.Formula = "=1"
For i = 1 To iterationCount
    cell.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=" & cell.Address & " + 1"
    Set cell = cell.Offset(, 1)
Next
```